# Can't resolve internal/private DNS entries over VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I have a basic VPN setup that allows me to connect to my AWS VPC via an OpenVPN client (tunnelblick 3.5). There is an OpenVPN sever (Ubuntu 12.4) that is running in the VPC which creates the connection. The VPN works fine as i am able to ping any private IP address in my VPC. My problem is that I cannot ping any of my private/internal DNS entires that point to private IP addresses.

For example, I can ping the the private IP `10.10.10.10`, but I can't ping the private DNS entry `server.pvt.company.com`, which points to `10.10.10.10`.

If I SSH onto any instance in the VPC I can ping `server.pvt.company.com`, and it resolves to `10.10.10.10`, but this fails to work on my local when the VPN connection is up.

Here is my OpenVPN server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert blah.crt
key blah.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
```

Here is my OpenVPN client.conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote blah.company.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert me.crt
key me.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Any suggestions for figuring out how to resolve or push private/internal DNS entires over an OpenVPN  connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is pushing the Google DNS servers to the client:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

You'll want to push a local DNS server that knows how to resolve your local hostnames instead.

Comment: thanks @heavyd! I added push "route 169.254.169.253" and
push "dhcp-option DNS 169.254.169.253" to my openvpn server.conf and i can now resolve private dns entries over vpn. I used 169.254.169.253 as my local dns servers b/c according to aws documentation that is the ip for aws dns server http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html